# Can I install MVC4 without installing .Net Framework 4.5

Tags: windows-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

Our server team does not want to install MVC4 on the DEV server if it includes .Net Framework 4.5.  Is there an install of MVC4 that does not in 4.5?

I googled, but came up with nothing definitive.

Note:  MVC4 Beta is on the DEV Server now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [download page for MVC 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683) (Emphasis mine)

> PowerShell 2.0, **.NET 4, ASP.NET 4**, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 or Visual Web Developer 2010 SP1 are required to use this feature.

I.e. only the .Net Framework version 4.0 is required, not 4.5.